# I have a treeview with datagrids in WPF. I need the strikethrough the datagridcell value based on some conditions

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

I need to strike the datagridcell value in datagrid.

```
<TreeView Name="treeview_Fleets" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewItems}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding ElementName=A350FleetMgmtEPDS, Path= DataContext.IsExpanded }"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}"   DataType="{x:Type m:Key}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeyId}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Key}">
                    <DataGrid Name="dgSubFleet_MSN"  GridLinesVisibility="All" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" CellStyle="{DynamicResource BackgroundStyle}"  ColumnWidth="90" Tag="{Binding DataContext,ElementName=treeview_Fleets}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False">
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I have a treeview as above.

And I need to strike through the individual cellvalue based on some conditions. I am using the style as below

```
 <Style x:Key="CellStyle_Strike" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations"   Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsObsoleteToTextDecorationsConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

And also i am using IsObsoleteToTextDecorationsConverter converter as below.

```
public class IsObsoleteToTextDecorationsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (A350FleetMgmtEPDSWindowViewModel.flag == true)
            {
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
                List<string> Strike_list = new List<string>();
                Strike_list = (A350FleetMgmtEPDSWindowViewModel.Strikthrough_List);
                string input = "";
                DataGridCell dgc = (DataGridCell)value;
                //DataGridTextColumn dgtc = (DataGridTextColumn)value;
                System.Data.DataRowView rowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)dgc.DataContext;
                try
                {
                    input = (string)rowView.Row.ItemArray[dgc.Column.DisplayIndex];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                    {
                        if (Strike_list.Contains(input))
                        {TextDecorationCollection redStrikthroughTextDecoration = TextDecorations.Strikethrough.CloneCurrentValue();
                            redStrikthroughTextDecoration[0].Pen = new Pen { Brush = Brushes.Red, Thickness = 3 };
                            return redStrikthroughTextDecoration;
}
                        return new TextDecorationCollection();
                    }
                }

                catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                {
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
                    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
                }

            }

<TreeView Name="treeview_Fleets" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewItems}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding ElementName=A350FleetMgmtEPDS, Path= DataContext.IsExpanded }"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}"   DataType="{x:Type m:Key}">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeyId}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Key}">
                                                    <DataGrid Name="dgSubFleet_MSN"  GridLinesVisibility="All" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" CellStyle="{DynamicResource BackgroundStyle}"  ColumnWidth="90" Tag="{Binding DataContext,ElementName=treeview_Fleets}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False">
                                                    </DataGrid>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                </TreeView>
I have a treeview as above.
And i need to strike through the individual cellvalue based on some conditions.I am using the style as below
 <Style x:Key="CellStyle_Strike" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations"   Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsObsoleteToTextDecorationsConverter}}"/>
</Style>

And also i am using IsObsoleteToTextDecorationsConverter converter.
as below.
public class IsObsoleteToTextDecorationsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (A350FleetMgmtEPDSWindowViewModel.flag == true)
            {
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
                List<string> Strike_list = new List<string>();
                Strike_list = (A350FleetMgmtEPDSWindowViewModel.Strikthrough_List);
                string input = "";
                DataGridCell dgc = (DataGridCell)value;
                //DataGridTextColumn dgtc = (DataGridTextColumn)value;
                System.Data.DataRowView rowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)dgc.DataContext;
                try
                {
                    input = (string)rowView.Row.ItemArray[dgc.Column.DisplayIndex];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                    {
                        if (Strike_list.Contains(input))
                        {TextDecorationCollection redStrikthroughTextDecoration = TextDecorations.Strikethrough.CloneCurrentValue();
                            redStrikthroughTextDecoration[0].Pen = new Pen { Brush = Brushes.Red, Thickness = 3 };
                            return redStrikthroughTextDecoration;
}
                        return new TextDecorationCollection();
                    }
                }

                catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                {
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
                    return  DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
                }

            }
```

I need to strike the datagridcell value in datagrid

I have a treeview as above.
And i need to strike through the individual cellvalue based on some conditions.I am using the style as below

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have all the components there, the only thing you need to do now, is define DataGrid Columns (right now they would be Auto Generated), Set AutoGenerateColumns="False" on the Datagrid and then set the Style for the column you want to show StrikeThrough. Something like this:

```
    <DataGrid Name="dgSubFleet_MSN"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"   GridLinesVisibility="All" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" CellStyle="{DynamicResource BackgroundStyle}"  ColumnWidth="90" Tag="{Binding DataContext,ElementName=treeview_Fleets}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Your Column Header" Binding="{Binding Your Field}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Path=Your Field based on which you want to bind,  Converter={StaticResource IsObsoleteToTextDecorationsConverter }}" />
               </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
       </DataGridTextColumn>
    ... Other Columns ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I my treeview with DataGrid, i am giving the treeviewItems  as itemsource.In that treeview items i am having Datatables. In codebehind i have datatables and in view(XAML) i have datagrid. To populate datatables , i am using Datagrid.

Comment: I my treeview with DataGrid, i am giving the treeviewItems  as itemsource.In that treeview items i am having Datatables. In codebehind i have datatables and in view(XAML) i have datagrid. To populate datatables , i am using Datagrid.  Now my question is .............How to strike the value in the datagridcell  . As i am not having any columns in datagrid in treeview. Dynamically the columns are getting generated.